# Caret regexp produces no output in mawk

Tags: awk

I am trying to print all files in `/usr/bin/` where the filename starts with a `v`. This works,

`ls -lA /usr/bin/ | awk '{print $9}' | grep ^v`

Surprisingly, this returns no output,

`ls -lA /usr/bin/ | awk '/^v/ {print $9}'`.

I don't understand the difference. I am running `Ubuntu 21.10` with `awk -W version` saying that it is on `1.3.4 20200120`.

**Edit:** I understand that `awk` may not be the best way to accomplish what I am wanting to do here. But, this is an exercise in learning awk by testing my understanding via comparing it to the real output.

Comment: Regarding `grep ^v` - it's not the problem you're asking about but **ALWAYS** quote strings (including scripts) in shell unless you have a specific reason not to so that should be `grep '^v'`. Quotes aren't something you add when you need to, they're something you remove when you need to. Make sure to read and fully understand https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes before writing any other shell scripts.

Comment: Regarding `ls ... | awk` - please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs to understand why not to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between the two pipelines is that the first outputs the 9th column and then check to see if that starts with a `v` the second checks to see if the line starts with a `v`, change the second to:

```
$ ls -lA /usr/bin/ | awk '$9 ~ /^v/ {print $9}'
```

When writing:

```
/pattern/ { ... }
```

it's the same as writing

```
$0 ~ /pattern/ { ... }
```

but in your case you want to compare the 9th column, so write that instead.

---

But you really don't want to create a pipeline for this, and what would happen if your files contain a space?

You can consider using `find` or globs instead:

```
$ printf '%s\n' /usr/bin/v*
/usr/bin/vi
/usr/bin/view
...
```

or

```
$ find /usr/bin -name 'v*' -print
/usr/bin/vi
/usr/bin/view
...
```

Comment: I apologise, but see the edit.

Comment: @scribe ? I don't think you read my answer?

Comment: I did. Was just pointing out that while `printf` and `find`maybe better, the objective in this case is to understand why `awk` did not work. So--you answered my question with just the first half and was trying to save you some further edits.